# Is there a way to reference objects in a registry as if it was an enum?

Tags: php

I'm working on a web game project which has the concept of items.

Individual instances of items, which a user could have in their inventory, are stored in the database. Each of those rows has a column called `item_base` which is used in the code to get details about the item. Example:

| unique_item_id | player_id | item_base |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3345346 | 43455 | ITEM_ONE |
| 3856739 | 97212 | ITEM_TWO |

My `ItemBase` class:

```
class ItemBase {

    public $name;
    public $type;
    public $action;

    public function __construct(string $name, ItemType $type, callable $action) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->type = $type->value;
        $this->action = $action();
    }

}
```

The `ItemType` enum is just a standard enum that returns a string to prevent typos.

I'm looking to "register" all of my item bases in the codebase rather than its own table in the database since I want to prevent additional queries. Each item base also has a function (`$action`) to determine which code should be executed when the item is used, and I'm avoiding putting PHP directly into the database.

Creating a new item base would be like this:

```
new ItemBase("Item One", ItemType::FOOD, function() {
    //Code to execute when the function is called
});
```

**My goal is to be able to reference item bases with something like `ItemBase::ITEM_ONE`***.* Then I can use `ItemBase::ITEM_ONE->name` or the other variables passed through the construct.

What is the best way to approach this? Being able to have the defined type (which IDEs also support type completion on) is preferred over using an $array['string'] lookup. Since enums can't be backed by an object, can I do something with a registry type class?

I've tried creating a class with all of my ItemBases in them and then registering each one similar to this:

```
public static function ITEM_ONE() {
    return new ItemBase("Item One", ItemType::FOOD, function() {
        //Code to execute when the function is called
});
```

This then allows me to use `ItemBase::ITEM_ONE()`, but I'm looking for a method that doesn't require a function for each item base in the game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regsitry class and the [`__callStatic`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.callstatic) magic method

```php
class ItemStore {
    protected static $store = [];

    public static function registerItem($key, $name, $type, $action) {
        self::$store[$key] = compact("name", "type", "action");
    }

    public static function __callStatic($key, $args) {
        if (array_key_exists($key, self::$store)) {
            return new ItemBase(
                self::$store[$key]["name"],
                self::$store[$key]["type"],
                self::$store[$key]["action"]
            );
        }
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException("$key is not a valid item");
    }
}

// demo

try {
    echo ItemStore::ITEM_ONE()->name;
} catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
echo "\n";

ItemStore::registerItem("ITEM_ONE", "Item One", "Food", function () {
    return "foo";
});
echo ItemStore::ITEM_ONE()->name;
echo "\n";
echo ItemStore::ITEM_ONE()->action;
```

> ITEM_ONE is not a valid item
>
> Item One
>
> foo

You could optionally define the registry stuff on the `ItemBase` class instead of making a separate `ItemStore` class.

Comment: Thank you! This fits my needs although I need to see if I can get PHPStorm to autocomplete the potential options when using the `__callStatic` magic method. I'm able to call these bases dynamically by getting the string value from the database then using `ItemBase::{$item->base_item}()`.

Comment: Phpstorm will autocomplete if you provide `@method` phpdoc for each method, meaning you'd still need to specify a doc comment for each method, which is annoying, but I don't think there's any sort of dynamic autocomplete you can do. If you figure that out lmk!

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the name of the enum entry as key in a lookup array? It is a distinct value, so perfectly usable as key in a map.

```
enum ItemType {
  case FOOD;
  case DRINK;
}

readonly class ItemBase {

  public function __construct(
    public string   $name,
    // public ItemType $itemType,   // not needed, as the key in $registry is the link
    public Closure  $action
  ) {}

}

$registry = [
  ItemType::FOOD->name  => new ItemBase('Item One', fn() => 'food'),
  ItemType::DRINK->name => new ItemBase('Item One', fn() => 'drink'),
];

echo $registry[ItemType::FOOD->name]->name;
echo "\n";
echo ($registry[ItemType::FOOD->name]->action)();
```

Output:

```
Item One
food
```

Note the parentheses around the lookup and property access for *action*. The parentheses are necessary because the function call () has higher precedence than the property access with ->.

Or the same with a (type safe) registry class:

```
enum ItemType {
  case FOOD;
  case DRINK;
}

readonly class ItemBase {

  public function __construct(
    public string  $name,
    public ItemType $itemType,
    public Closure $action
  ) {}

}

readonly class Registry implements ArrayAccess {

  private array $items;

  public function __construct(
    ItemBase ...$itemBases
  ) {
    $items = [];
    foreach ($itemBases as $item) {
      $items[$item->itemType->name] = $item;
    }
    $this->items = $items;
  }

  final public function offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool {
    return is_string($offset) && array_key_exists($offset, $this->items);
  }

  final public function offsetGet(mixed $offset): mixed {
    return $this->offsetExists($offset) ? $this->items[$offset] : null;
  }

  final public function offsetSet(mixed $offset, mixed $value): void {
    throw new RuntimeException();
  }

  final public function offsetUnset(mixed $offset): void {
    throw new RuntimeException();
  }

}

$registry = new Registry(
  new ItemBase('Item One', ItemType::FOOD, fn() => 'food'),
  new ItemBase('Item One', ItemType::DRINK, fn() => 'drink'),
);

echo $registry[ItemType::FOOD->name]->name;
echo "\n";
echo ( $registry[ItemType::FOOD->name]->action )();
```